# Why aren't blatantly off-topic questions closed consistently?

Tags: discussion, flags, questions, scope

I flagged both https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980496/how-to-create-windows-7-shortcut-for-manage-audio-devices and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863348/bluetooth-issue-with-android-4-0 as off-topic because they have nothing to do with programming.

The flags were marked "helpful", but the questions were never closed. Why is that?

Comment: Because they didn't receive enough votes. That could be the result of any number of factors. the first one is now closed due to folks seeing it here.

Comment: A little patience! The posts are in less-frequented tags, the close review queue is large. Your flags were automatically marked as helpful because subsequent reviews in the review queue agreed with your assessment, but more votes are needed to close those posts.

Comment: Because you do not have 3K rep yet, so you cannot help us. Get to work :)

Comment: Do keep in mind that this may well be intentional.  It doesn't take much time lurking at SO to realize that using a high-volume tag like [windows] or [android] gets such a question closed in a manner of minutes.

Comment: @HansPassant: It also gets 20 low-quality answers in that time though...

Comment: Possibly because they are on-topic for another site (e.g. superuser), and the questions should have been moved, not closed.

Comment: @Parthian, why would that affect closure(/migration) speed?

Comment: @OGHaza Short answer: I honestly don't know. Since I can neither `move` nor `close` questions, I don't know what the algorithm is. Longer answer: Since SO is usually pretty democratic, if post closure is also democratic I could see moderators casting move votes as causing a delay in question closure. As in, it would take longer to garner enough close votes to pass the motion... Or, at least, it should...

Comment: I don't know how moving works exactly, but things that should be moved should be moved as quickly as possible—otherwise they tend to gather a lot of downvotes before they reach their final destination.

Comment: @Par Migration works the same as closing (though old questions can't be migrated). 5 votes does it. You can e.g. Close -> Unclear, or Close -> Belongs on another site -> SuperUser. Generally only questions deemed to be very good, and hence beneficial to the other site, will be migrated rather than closed.

Comment: Both questions don't exist anymore.

Answer (score 24):

You are casting **recommend closure** flags. These are not ordinary flags, and **moderators do not ever see them**. These flags will push the question into the Close Votes queue for review.

They are automatically dismissed as helpful the moment someone casts a full vote to close with the same reason you selected in your flag. That means with **only one** real vote to close, your flag is helpful and is done, and that vote to close will carry that review item from here on out. Note that if there is more than one recommend closure flag on the post, they get dismissed one-by-one in the order they were received, so it could take multiple votes before *yours* gets dismissed. All recommend closure flags, whether that reason was selected or not, are dismissed as helpful if the question gets closed at any point.

So what you're seeing is another user validating your flag while the question is still pending closure. They will likely get closed in the future, and both of the Close Votes review tasks for those questions *were* still active at the time they got closed by the Meta visitors you attracted.